# 3d fisheye - how to make bars wider on mouseover?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, width, fisheye

I'm using this d3 example with fisheye implemented. Basically, the group element holds rect and text elements. How to make groups (bar+txt) wider on mouseover?

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/30114/w4tfr68s/

Code:

```
    var xFisheye = d3.fisheye.scale(d3.scale.identity).domain([0, width]).focus(1000);

...

    svg.on("mousemove", function() {
        var mouse = d3.mouse(this);
        xFisheye.focus(mouse[0]);

        redraw();
    });

    function redraw() {

        bars
            .attr("transform", function(d){

            return "translate("+ xFisheye(d) +",0) scale(1, 1)";

        });
    }
```

Comment: If a slight degree of distortion is acceptable, this could be as simple as changing the scale, say: `return "translate("+ xFisheye(d) +",0) scale(1.5, 1)";`

Comment: Hi, I already tried that but it scales all bars

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. So basically translating your bar with the original value of y multiplied by the scale factor worked for me.

```
function redraw(){
    bars
    .attr("transform", function(d) { 
         return "translate("+ xFisheye(d) +"," + y*1.2) + ") scale(1.2, 1.2)"; 
    });        
}
```

This should work.
If this helps, following is the code I used:

```
.on("mouseover", function(d) 
{
     tool_tip.show(d);
     d3.select(this)
     .attr("transform", function(d) 
     { 
         return "translate("+ x(d.x0) +"," + y(d.length*1.2) + ") scale(1.2, 1.2)"; 
     });        
})

.on("mouseout", function(d) 
{
     tool_tip.hide(d);
     d3.select(this)
     .attr("height", height - y(d.length))
     .attr("transform", function(d) 
     { 
         return "translate("+ x(d.x0) +"," + y(d.length) + ") scale(1, 1)";
     });
});
```